# svn checkout using build.xml

Tags: svn, ant, svn-checkout

I am trying to get code from svn repository placed in remote machine using ant build script. Currently the code is accessible from eclipse using svn plug in and its repository URL is like `https://remotemachinename/svn/MYAPP/trunk`.

I have placed all the required jars in the classpath and when I ran the following command from the command prompt I was able to check out all the files from trunk.

```
D:\SVNRepo\svn co https://remotemachinename/svn/MYAPP/trunk
```

but when I try it from build.xml I am facing the following error.

```
update:

      [svn] svn: E730061: Unable to connect to a repository at URL  `https://remotemachinename/svn/MYAPP/trunk`
      [svn] svn: E730061: Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
      [svn] <Checkout> failed.
      BUILD FAILED
```

build.xml

```
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />
 <svnSetting  svnkit="false" javahl="false" username="" password="" id="svn.settings"/> 

 <target name="update">
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
      <checkout url="${project.svn.url}" revision="HEAD" destPath="." />
    </svn>
 </target>
```

I have noticed couple of posts in stackoverfolow..but not able to fix this issue. Any help on this will be appreicated.

Thanks,
FS

Comment: I am able to fix this with following code change in build.xml   <exec executable="svn">
    <arg value="co"/>
    <arg value="https://remotemachinename/svn/MYAPP/trunk"/> </exec> Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how useful this will be to others, but...make it an answer?